# Hyper-V: Monitor and restart unresponsive hyper-v guests

Tags: ubuntu, monitoring, hyper-v, hyper-v-server-2012, shutdown

I'm looking for a simple solution to monitor and restart unresponsive Hyper-V guests.
I only need this solution for a handful of machines, and only around ten guests. It's mostly Ubuntu guests that run out of memory and become unresponsive.

I don't mind if the system works on a simple ping (rather than using heartbeat).
I would consider simple scripts that run on the host or another machine.

I guess the solution would need to attempt to stop the unresponsive VM gracefully for a while, and then to hard-stop it if that didn't work, finally to start it again.

Comment: I would hold off on asking this question until you have a response to your other question. This may become obsolete.

Comment: John, either way I need a simple solution to do the monitoring and revive unresponsive VMs. Even if they are more stable, I still want the solution in place.

Comment: why not just cluster the vms

Comment: Did you ever figure out a solution?

Comment: No. In the end we got rid of our bare metal and moved to hosted services anyway ... so the problem became someone else's.